# importXML is making too many Mapquest transactions

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, mapquest

I am trying to use the following formula and a key I obtained from mapquest (for the free service) to initiate their location services and calculate the distances between one variable location and 20 of my plant locations.

```
=importXML("http://mapquestapi.com/directions/v2/route?key=*****************&outFormat=xml&from=" & $B$3 & "&to=" & 56244,"//response/route/distance")
```

This is working flawlessly expect after using it for a short period of time I have received an email stating I have used 80% of my allotment (15000 transactions) for the month.

The variable location has only been changed around 20-25 times this month so I don't see how I could have used that many transactions. Can someone explain what exactly this formula is doing and how I could make it more efficient if possible? I feel like it has to be using transaction that are unnecessary. Keep in mind I do not need the actual directions all I need is the driving mileage required.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How many times is the import being called? Are you refreshing the results periodically to make those many calls?

Comment: I am not sure. I had that formula inserted in the cell next to each of my 20 plant locations. So each time I changed the variable location I assumed it would make 20 calls in order to refresh the distance to each of my plant locations. It shouldn't and doesn't appear to refresh anytime except when a new variable location is inserted.

Comment: Well, I just realized you had also posted your key to the API on this website. Sharing your key could definitely result in calls that you haven't made in case someone else uses your key. I have gone ahead and edited it out. But where are you calculating the distance to your plants from? Is that location static?

Comment: I had removed a few values from the key so that it wouldn't work when I posted it so that shouldn't be the cause.The 20 plant locations are static, then i input one variable location. That location is the project location. So the sheet calculates the distance from each of my plants to the project location.

Comment: Hmm.... is the formula applied to all rows in a particular column? So that whenever you change the variable location, all the columns get updated? If yes, I'd check if the rows that you are not using are calling the formula too. Good thing will be to delete the formula from those rows as well.